# Polynomials connected with Gale's condition and cyclic polytopes

Tags: reference-request, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, orthogonal-polynomials

I was reading about cyclic polytopes and (I think naturally) became interested in polynomials $f(X) \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ which have a factorization of the form $f(X)=g(X)g(X+1)$ for some $g(X) \in \mathbb{R}[X]$.

When such $f$ has degree $2n$ and vanishes at exactly $2n$ integers, then this set of zeros is a "Gale set".

Do these polynomials have a name?  (I think they deserve one!)  Also, are there any overt references to these polynomials in connection with either convex geometry or orthogonal polynomials?